# Laravel 5.6, email not not sending on server with sendmail driver

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.6 and i can send email on locale but not on server with sendmail driver.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your server don't have the driver or the smtp server installed.

But if you have Laravel, you should try SwiftMailer because it's a much more robust way to send emails that will work well on almost any scenario.

> Laravel provides a clean, simple API over the popular SwiftMailer
>   library.

Mail::send is just a laravel wrapper for swift mailer, so you are calling swift mailer when doing that call unless you change 'driver' => 'smtp' to 'driver' => 'mail', only then will it use the PHP's mail.

Reference: [Laravel Mail Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail)